# How do I get rid of this goto?

Tags: c#, foreach, refactoring, goto

I just started a position and at the end of the workday I wait out traffic by slowly reading through our codebase.  I came across this bit and even after a fair amount of time at the whiteboard I still can't think of a way to extract the `goto`.  Is there a way to excise this jump?

```
public void MyUpdate(MyType foo)
{
    /*Prep code for the loops*/        
    foreach (Thing bar in something)
    {
        foreach (Collection item in bar.Stuff)
        {
            Data dataRX = item.First;
            if (dataRX != null && dataRX.ID.Equals(globalNonsense.ID))
            {
                // Update Data with the latest changes
                dataRX.fooBuddy = foo;
                goto exitLoops;
            }
        }
    }

    exitLoops: ;
}
```

Comment: Why not `return` if `exitLoops` is at the end of the method?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Good idea, but in some coding standards, `return`ing from more than one location in a function is considered bad form, like goto.

Comment: I'd prefer the `return` solution. The mentioned code standards also don't like `break`s as in my answer. But I think these standards are often very theoretical and not to be taken _too_ serious in situations like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the label `exitLoops` is at the end of the method, then you can simply use `return` to exit the method like this:

```
if (dataRX != null && dataRX.ID.Equals(globalNonsense.ID))
{
    // Update Data with the latest changes
    dataRX.fooBuddy = foo;
    return;
}
```

Another approach is to use a flag like this:

```
bool done = false;

foreach (Thing bar in something)
{
    foreach (Collection item in bar.Stuff)
    {
        Data dataRX = item.First;
        if (dataRX != null && dataRX.ID.Equals(globalNonsense.ID))
        {
            // Update Data with the latest changes
            dataRX.fooBuddy = foo;
            done = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(done)
        break;
}
```

You can use the second approach even if there is some code after the label.

Comment: Now that you point it out, `return`-ing seems so obvious.  There used to be a lot of white space after the exitLoops label, I bet at some point there used to be more code in this function.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Move the inner loop to a method, and conditionally break based on its return value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so nice, but without implementing a complete new algorithm this seems the easiest way:

```
foreach (Thing bar in something)
{
    bool exitLoop = false;
    foreach (Collection item in bar.Stuff)
    {
        Data dataRX = item.First;
        if (dataRX != null && dataRX.ID.Equals(globalNonsense.ID))
        {
            // Update Data with the latest changes
            dataRX.fooBuddy = foo;
            exitLoop = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (exitLoop) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do this using LINQ:

```
public void MyUpdate(MyType foo)
{
    Thing dummy = something.FirstOrDefault(bar => bar.Stuff.SkipWhile((item) => 
    {
        Data dataRx = item.First;
        if (dataRx != null && dataRx.ID.Equals(globalNonsense.ID))
        {
            dataRx.fooBuddy = foo;
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }).Count() != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `foreach` you will need `break` or `return`. But without `break`, `return`, or `goto` there is this option:

```
public void MyUpdate(MyType foo)
{
    bool stop = false;

    /*Prep code for the loops*/        
    for (var i = 0; !stop && (i < something.Count); i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; !stop && (j < something[i].Stuff.Count); j++)
        {
            Data dataRX = something[i].Stuff[j].First;
            if (dataRX != null && dataRX.ID.Equals(globalNonsense.ID))
            {
                // Update Data with the latest changes
                dataRX.fooBuddy = foo;
                stop = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```